# How to server request one time and print data in One recyleryview in android

Tags: java, android

```
public class DailyFunctionReportFragment extends Fragment {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private TextView textView;
    private JsonObject postBehaviourObj;
    private String patientID;
    private String dateValue;
    private HashMap<String, List<VitalReportsDetails>> hm = new HashMap<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView communication_recyclerView;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.daily_function_report_fragment_layout, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        communication_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.communication_recyclerView);
        textView = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.style.MyActivityTheme);
        patientID = ((ReportsTabActvity) getActivity()).getmPatientID();
        dateValue = CommonUtils.getDateInyyyyMMdd();
        postBehaviourObj = new JsonObject();
        textView.setText(CommonUtils.getStartandEndDate());
        postBehaviourObj.addProperty("patientId", patientID);
        postBehaviourObj.addProperty("type", "Weekly");
        postBehaviourObj.addProperty("value", dateValue);

        serverCall();
        communicationserverCall();

        return fragmentView;
    }




    public void serverCall() {
        postBehaviourObj.addProperty("functionType", "Continence");
        ReUseComponets serverCall = new ReUseComponets(new PostVitalReportListner() {
            @Override
            public void postVitalReportDetailListner(VitalReportDetail result) {
                List<VitalReportData> dataList = result.getData();
                for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
                    hm.put(result.getData().get(i).getFunction(), result.getData().get(i).getDetails());
                }

                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                DailyFunctionReportAdapter adapter = new DailyFunctionReportAdapter(getActivity(), dataList, hm);
                recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.d("Resulset", result.toString());
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void showError(Throwable error) {
                Log.e("", "On Success Response" + error.toString());
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        serverCall.asynCallPostVitalReportDetail(postBehaviourObj);

    }


    public void communicationserverCall() {
        postBehaviourObj.addProperty("functionType", "Communication");
        ReUseComponets serverCall = new ReUseComponets(new PostVitalReportListner() {
            @Override
            public void postVitalReportDetailListner(VitalReportDetail result) {
                List<VitalReportData> dataList = result.getData();
                for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
                    hm.put(result.getData().get(i).getFunction(), result.getData().get(i).getDetails());
                }

                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                communication_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                communication_recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                DailyFunctionReportAdapter adapter = new DailyFunctionReportAdapter(getActivity(), dataList, hm);
                communication_recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                Log.d("Resulset", result.toString());
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void showError(Throwable error) {
                Log.e("", "On Success Response" + error.toString());
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        serverCall.asynCallPostVitalReportDetail(postBehaviourObj);

    }


}
```

This is my Code I am  requesting two requests with different Input parameters:-

```
 postBehaviourObj.addProperty("functionType", "Continence");
 postBehaviourObj.addProperty("functionType", "Communication");
```

I am  getting the same type of result format with different data when using the same adapter twice.

What I am trying to do, is to use only one data list and hm and passing in one adapter with one recycle view.  I can do this if I add both  `List<VitalReportData>` data list and hm in one and pass.

Please suggest me how I can achieve this.

Comment: @NickAsher i have to  add  dataList and dataList and hm ,hm in one dataList and hm and pass it in one adapter

Comment: private HashMap<String, List<VitalReportsDetails>> hm = new HashMap<>();  hashmap

Comment: @NickAsher did u understand